# JQuery select a value within a form

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

Does anyone know how to select a value from a textbox/dropdown/checkbox within a form.

So if my form has an ID of "frm_1" and there is a textbox with ID "txt" how can I get that value using super JQuery?

I've tried a number of things but nothing lovely comes out. Here is the link, I'm just in design stage so please excuse the silly IDs! :O

http://pastebin.com/wbyL7qPt

Merry Christmas all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function:

```
var value = $('#txt').val();
```

Comment: that does work but I need the value fo the textbox within the form

Comment: @LooDaFunk, as long as your textbox has an unique ID there's no problem. Just use this unique id and you will get to the required value. Remember that IDs should be unique within the whole HTML document.